# Getting an unbound identifier 'require' in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket, sicp

I am using Drracket for my project. I am using the language SICP(**#lang sicp**) for my project. For one of my implementations i require the use of scheme package called `(require (planet dyoo/simply-scheme))`. Scheme is not recognising require keyword. But if i change my language to **#lang racket** "require" is recognised as an keyword. My project makes use of `set-car!` *and* `set-cdr!` which is available in sicp language and not in racket. Is there any work around.

Below is some excerpts of my code:

```
#lang sicp
(require (planet dyoo/simply-scheme))
(define crosscuts 0)
```

and

```
(define (move-north steps_to_move)
(set-cdr! current_position ( + (y_coord current_position) steps_to_move)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, here are things that I want to note:

1. It's generally better to use `#lang racket` because `#lang sicp` is very limited. You can still access `set-car!` (though it's named `set-mcar!`). See the documentation at https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/mpairs.html.
2. In case you decide to use `#lang racket`, do you actually need to use mutable data structure? Avoiding mutation is a defining trait of functional programming. And if you really do need mutable data structure, can you use `struct` with `#:mutable` instead? It's more Racket-y. See the documentation at https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/define-struct.html.
3. This might not be possible, but generally I would avoid using Planet package. Planet is an old package system that is no longer recommended. It looks like there's no `simply-scheme` in the new package system, however, so you might really need to use Planet here.

If you really want to use `#lang sicp`, note the margin note at https://docs.racket-lang.org/sicp-manual/SICP_Language.html

> R5RS has no `require` to avoid breaking programs that use the name `require`. `#%require` is therefore used instead.

`#%require` is a much more primitive operation, however. Depending on your require spec, it might or might not be easy to switch from `require` to `#%require`.

So first, try to replace `require` with `#%require` and see if it works. If it is, great, you are done.

But if it errors, then it means your require spec can't be processed by `#%require`. One possible solution is to use `#%require` to get `require` from Racket, so that you can use `require` to do more complex things.

```
(#%require (only racket require))
(require ....)
```